# How to fit "Negative Binomial" Distribution on a histogram using ggplot2()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, distribution

I am working with a dataset that I believe follows a "*Negative Binomial*" distribution. However, when I fit the *Negative Binomial* distribution, it turns out to be a poor fit. To explore further, I simulated a Negative Binomial distribution, but even on the simulated data, the overlaying distribution does not provide a good fit.

Here is my simulated data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)  
library(fitdistrplus)
# Generating negative binomial random numbers
n <- 1000  # Number of random numbers
size <- 5  # Number of successes
prob <- 0.3  # Probability of success

# Generating negative binomial random numbers
negative_binomial <- rnbinom(n, size, prob)
xx <- data.frame(negative_binomial)
```

I want to create a histogram with an overlay of the '*Negative Binomial*' distribution on this data. Let's assume that I was given this data, so I had to estimate the parameters of the distribution using `fitdist()`.

```
fit <- fitdistr(negative_binomial,densfun = "negative binomial")
ggplot(data = xx, aes(negative_binomial)) +
  geom_histogram(
    aes(y = ..density..),
    bins = 18, color = "black", fill = "lightblue") +
  stat_function(fun = dnbinom ,
    args = list(mu = fit$estimate[2] , size = fit$estimate[1]),
    color = "red", size = 1)
```

**Question**: Despite knowing that the simulated data is `Negative Binomial`, why does the overlaying distribution provide such a poor fit to the data? What did I do wrong?

[image]

Comment: *a dataset that I believe follows a "Negative Binomial" distribution.* How, why?

Comment: My real data is a count data and based on historical data I know that data follows a Negative Binomial Dist. But plz forget about my real data and tell me why Negative Binomial is a poor fit on simulated "Negative Binomial" data?

Comment: Usually, when you are interested in the distribution, you are interested in the distribution conditional on predictors. In particular, you would care about a negative binomial distribution if you intend to fit a generalized linear model (GLM) with the negative-binomial distribution family. Fitting the distribution to the data is not helpful for that purpose. So, why are you doing this?

Comment: **non-integer x**: `hist(xx$negative_binomial, prob = TRUE, col = "lightblue", breaks = 18L); curve(dnbinom(x, mu = fit$estimate[2L], size = fit$estimate[1L]), 0L, 40L, col = "red", add = TRUE)` issues warnings that say: "~you are treating a discrete distribution as continuous".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue is that you are trying to plot a discrete distribution but feed the density function continuous values (which means it returns 0 for most of them).

```
fit <- fitdist(negative_binomial, distr = "nbinom")

yy <- data.frame(negative_binomial = 0:45)
yy$density <- dnbinom(yy$negative_binomial, 
                     mu = fit$estimate["mu"] , size = fit$estimate["size"])

ggplot(data = xx, aes(negative_binomial)) +
  geom_histogram(
    aes(y = ..density..),
    binwidth = 1, color = "black", fill = "lightblue") +
  geom_linerange(data = yy, aes(ymin = 0, ymax = density),
                color = "red")
```

[image: resulting plot showing a histogram of the data and the fitted distribution]